# jQuery disable a link

Tags: jquery, hyperlink

Anyone know how to disable a link in jquery WITHOUT using `return false;`?

Specifically, what I'm trying to do is disable the link of an item, performing a click on it using jquery which triggers some stuff, then re-enabling that link so that if it's clicked again it works as default.

Thanks.
Dave

**UPDATE**
Here's the code. What it needs to do after the `.expanded` class has been applied is to re-enable the disabled link.

```
$('ul li').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('ul').addClass('expanded');
    $('ul.expanded').fadeIn(300);
    //return false;
});
```

Comment: Why the requirement not to use return false? Use it, and then delete the event handler when it no longer applies (or put a conditional in it to return different values depending on the status of the mentioned "some stuff").

Comment: Are you just trying to do some pre-processing before the link is followed on the same click action? i.e. you aren't proposing two clicks but rather user clicks link, some actions happen, link is followed?

Comment: Otherwise, can you explain why you are taking this approach as a better understanding of the problem space will improve the answers.

Comment: @lazarus, I'm proposing 2 clicks on the same link. 1 to do some stuff first, then the 2nd to treat the link as a link.

Comment: @daviddorward, So far I've tried return false and it carries on through to the second part of my goal, ie not allowing the 2nd click to go through. 

If you could write a short example I'd be most grateful.

Comment: @David Dorward return false only works if there are no errors. It makes it very difficult to debug when the page reloads before you can see what happened.

Comment: I have this same issue, and removing 'href' doesn't work well for me in my case because I may need that value. Therefore, I was considering positioning an opacity:0 DIV on top of the hyperlink temporarily. One would have to implement cross-platform opacity:0, however.

Answer (score 377, accepted):

```
$('#myLink').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //do other stuff when a click happens
});
```

That will prevent the default behaviour of a hyperlink, which is to visit the specified href.

From the jQuery [tutorial](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:How_jQuery_Works):

> For click and most other events, you
>   can prevent the default behaviour -
>   here, following the link to jquery.com
>   - by calling event.preventDefault() in the event handler

If you want to `preventDefault()` only if a certain condition is fulfilled (something is hidden for instance), you could test the visibility of your ul with the class **expanded**. If it is visible (i.e. not hidden) the link should fire as normal, as the if statement will not be entered, and thus the default behaviour will not be prevented:

```
$('ul li').click(function(e) {
    if($('ul.expanded').is(':hidden')) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('ul').addClass('expanded');
        $('ul.expanded').fadeIn(300);
    } 
});
```

Comment: With jQuery 1.7+ you can use on/off:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209029/best-way-to-remove-an-event-handler-in-jquery

Comment: if it has an href and onclick this will work             $("#myLink").attr('onclick', '').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
            });

Comment: realized through ajax and jquery I can hide a href buy having the callback to keep scrapers from getting these links. Awesome thanks!

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17935158/2218697) post has **easiest way using bootstrap**, hope helps.

Comment: @LanceCleveland The solution you linked to does not work for anchor tags.

Answer (score 118):

Try this:

```
$("a").removeAttr('href');
```

**EDIT-**

From your updated code:

```
 var location= $('#link1').attr("href");
 $("#link1").removeAttr('href');
 $('ul').addClass('expanded');
 $('ul.expanded').fadeIn(300);
 $("#link1").attr("href", location);
```

Comment: Playing with href is very nice because is a fast way of disabiling a link which does action via a onclick event. Very very Clever!

Comment: sweet method to keep the browser from adding the # within the URI when doing `href="#"`

Answer (score 70):

For others who came here via google like me - here's another approach:

```
css:
.disabled {
  color: grey; // ...whatever
}

jQuery:
$('#myLink').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if ($(this).hasClass('disabled'))
    return false; // Do something else in here if required
  else
    window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
});

// Elsewhere in your code
if (disabledCondition == true)
  $('#myLink').addClass('disabled')
else
  $('#myLink').removeClass('disabled')
```

Remember: not only this is a css class

> class="buttonstyle"

but also these two

> class="buttonstyle disabled"

so you can easily add and remove further classes with jQuery. No need to touch href...

I love jQuery! ;-)

Comment: this assumes that the link has no target :)

Comment: Instead of doing all of this fancyness, why not just tack the onclick higher in the dom, use `on()` to filter all `a.disabled` links and prevent default.  Then all you have to do is toggle the disabled class on/off and the link will handle itself when "enabled".

Comment: No need for the "== true" -- addClass('disabled') will run regardless.

`if(disabledCondition)`

Comment: @fwilson, while you're totally correct, for a beginning programmer, it is easier to understand with the ``== true``.  :)

Comment: Any particular reason not to simplify it to `if ($(this).hasClass('disabled')) {
    e.preventDefault();
}`?

Answer (score 64):

Here is an alternate css/jQuery solution that I prefer for its terseness and minimized scripting:

css:

```
a.disabled {
  opacity: 0.5;
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: default;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('.disableAfterClick').click(function (e) {
   $(this).addClass('disabled');
});
```

Comment: [From Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/pointer-events): "Warning: The use of pointer-events in CSS for non-SVG elements is experimental. The feature used to be part of the CSS3 UI draft specification but, due to many open issues, has been postponed to CSS4."

Comment: Thats a good consideration, but it happens to work well in most of the modern browsers.

Comment: You might want to consider chaining `.prop("tabindex", "-1");` after the `addClass`

Answer (score 22):

You can remove click for link by following;

```
$('#link-id').unbind('click');
```

You can re-enable link by followings,

```
$('#link-id').bind('click');
```

*You can not use 'disabled'  property for links.*

Comment: Easy to toggle on and off compared to others.

Comment: "You can not use 'disabled' property for links."  Wonder why there is no consistency between a button, and a link for disabling. "disabled" should work for a link too. It's like saying for a Chevy car you must hit the brake pedal to stop, but for this other car manufacturer, you must use this lever located on the roof.

Comment: As of jQuery 3.0, `.unbind()` has been deprecated. It was superseded by the `.off()` method since jQuery 1.7. Docs: https://api.jquery.com/unbind/

Answer (score 16):

If you go the href route, you can save it

To disable:

```
$('a').each(function(){
    $(this).data("href", $(this).attr("href")).removeAttr("href");
});
```

Then re-enable using:

```
$('a').each(function(){
    $(this).attr("href", $(this).data("href"));
});
```

In one case I had to do it this way because the click events were already bound somewhere else and I had no control over it.

Answer (score 14):

I always use this in jQuery for disabling links

```
$("form a").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

Comment: You also can use `$("form a").attr("disabled", false);` to make it enabled again

Answer (score 12):

html link example:

```
        <!-- boostrap button + fontawesome icon -->
        <a class="btn btn-primary" id="BT_Download" target="_blank" href="DownloadDoc?Id=32">
        <i class="icon-file-text icon-large"></i>
        Download Document
        </a>
```

use this in jQuery

```
    $('#BT_Download').attr('disabled',true);
```

add this to css :

```
    a[disabled="disabled"] {
        pointer-events: none;
    }
```

Comment: I'd never come across this CSS property before but this, for me, is by far the simplest method for disabling a hyperlink. The beauty of it is that when you remove the class which contains the `pointer-events: none` property from the anchor elements they revert to doing whatever they did previously when clicked. So if they were basic hyperlinks, they revert to navigating to the URL in their `href` attribute, and if they have a click event handler set, that becomes active again. Much simpler than saving `href` values and click handlers.

Comment: I like this solution, it is the simplest one.

Comment: Out of a handful of "solutions" when nothing worked (and almost giving up this route), came to this **gem**. It's a no-fuss solution. And the only one which REALLY WORKS. Kudos.

Comment: awesome just brilliant

Answer (score 5):

My fav in "checkout to edit an item and prevent -wild wild west clicks to anywhere- while in a checkout" functions

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
    var = $(this).attr('disabled');
    if (var === 'disabled') {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

So if i want that all external links in a second action toolbar should be disabled while in the "edit-mode" as described above, i'll add in the edit function

```
$('#actionToolbar .external').attr('disabled', true);
```

Link example after fire:

```
<a href="http://goo.gl" target="elsewhere" class="external" disabled="disabled">Google</a>
```

*And now you CAN use disabled property for links*

Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

you can just hide and show the link as you like

```
$(link).hide();
$(link).show();
```

Comment: you can it's just not great ux though.

Answer (score 3):

Just trigger stuff, set some flag, return false. If flag is set - do nothing.

Comment: Have tried that by setting a class, then calling that class later but return false carries through, and prevents the link from being called.

Answer (score 3):

You should find you answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586024/disabling-links-with-jquery).

Thanks @Will and @Matt for this elegant solution.

```
jQuery('#path .to .your a').each(function(){
    var $t = jQuery(this);
    $t.after($t.text());
    $t.remove();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`unbind()` was deprecated in `jQuery 3`, use the `off()` method instead:

```
$("a").off("click");
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't with jQuery but you can disable a link with some simple css:

```css
a[disabled] {
  z-index: -1;
}
```

the HTML would look like

```html
<a disabled="disabled" href="/start">Take Survey</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just set preventDefault and return false

```
   $('#your-identifier').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
```

This will be disabled link but still, you will see a **clickable** icon(**hand**) icon. You can remove that too with below

```
$('#your-identifier').css('cursor', 'auto');
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for links that have the onclick attribute set inline.  This also allows you to later remove the "return false" in order to enable it.

```
        //disable all links matching class
        $('.yourLinkClass').each(function(index) {
            var link = $(this);
            var OnClickValue = link.attr("onclick");
            link.attr("onclick", "return false; " + OnClickValue);
        });

        //enable all edit links
        $('.yourLinkClass').each(function (index) {
            var link = $(this);
            var OnClickValue = link.attr("onclick");
            link.attr("onclick", OnClickValue.replace("return false; ", ""));
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

As a back-end engineer, it took me a while to wrap my head around how to do this but here is how i solved the exact same problem.

```
﻿const resendCodeTimeOutPeriodInMs = 30000; // 30seconds.

function resend2faCodeOnLogin(sendByEmail) {

const resendCodeLinkElement = $('#resendCodeLink');

const disabledState = resendCodeLinkElement.attr('disabled');
if (disabledState === 'disabled') {
    resendCodeLinkElement.preventDefault();
} else {
    resendCodeLinkElement.attr("disabled", true);
    resendCodeLinkElement.addClass('disabled');

    submitForm('#twoFactorResendCodeForm', (response) => {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('#resendCodeLink').removeClass('disabled');
            resendCodeLinkElement.attr("disabled", false);
        }, resendCodeTimeOutPeriodInMs); 

    }, (response) => {
        console.error(response);
    });
}
}
```

Standard CSS taken from well known examples off the web:

```
a.disabled {
opacity: 0.5;
pointer-events: none;
cursor: default;
```

My Approach was to ensure a given button is disabled for 30s before the UX can click it again.

Answer (score -2):

Just use `$("a").prop("disabled", true);`.
This will really disable de link element. 
Needs to be `prop("disabled", true)`. Don't use `attr("disabled", true)`