# Prevent window scroll jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I'm developing a select menu replacement in jquery.
First I've to make the new select menu focusable by just adding `tabindex="0"` to the container.
Then, I disable focus on the original select menu and give focus to the new one.
When the new one is focused and you press the up and down arrows the options change accordingly but there's a big problem. As you press the arrows the body moves too.
I tried all these solutions so far with no luck:

```
$(window).unbind('scroll');
$(document).unbind('scroll');
$('body').unbind('scroll');
$(window).unbind('keydown');
$(document).unbind('keydown');
```

Check the code here http://pastebin.com/pVNMqyui
This code is from the development version of Ideal Forms http://code.google.com/p/idealforms that I'm about to release soon, with keyboard support.

Any ideas why this is not working?

**EDIT:** Solved!

Found the answer on this post [jquery link tag enable disable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169625/jquery-link-tag-enable-disable)

```
var disableScroll = function(e){
    if (e.keyCode === 40 || e.keyCode === 38) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
};
// And then...
events.focus: function(){ $(window).on('keydown', disableScroll); }
events.blur: function(){ $(window).off('keydown', disableScroll); }
```

It works!

Comment: perhaps this is a job for `event.preventDefault();` in the handler for any event that might cause the window to scroll...

Comment: You should add this as an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer on this post [jquery link tag enable disable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169625/jquery-link-tag-enable-disable)

```
var disableScroll = function(e){
    if (e.keyCode === 40 || e.keyCode === 38) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
};
// And then...
events.focus: function(){ $(window).on('keydown', disableScroll); }
events.blur: function(){ $(window).off('keydown', disableScroll); }
```

Answer (score 2):

In your keydown handler, for up and down keys, return false like this:

```
'keydown' : function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 40) { // Down arrow
        that.events.moveOne('down');
    }
    if (e.keyCode === 38) { // Up arrow
        that.events.moveOne('up');
    }
    return false;
}
```

Also, make sure this return gets propagated to the browser's native onkeydown depending on how/which framework you're using.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cancel the keydown event for arrow keys.  Use either `e.preventDefault()` or `return false` in your `.keydown()` handler if an arrow key has been pressed.

Answer (score -1):

Its very simple.you need not even need jQuery for this.

jQuery:

```
$("body").css("overflow", "hidden");
```

javascript

```
<body style="overflow: hidden">
```

Adding in style:

```
<style>
 body {width:100%; height:100%; overflow:hidden, margin:0}
 html {width:100%; height:100%; overflow:hidden}
</style>
```

if you want to bind the arrow keys,try something like:

```
$('body').keydown(function(e){
    e.preventDefult();
    if(e.keyCode == 37) // for left key
    {
        // implement focus functionality
    }
    if(e.keyCode == 38) // for up key
    {
        // implement focus functionality
    }
    if(e.keyCode == 39) // for right key
    {
        // implement focus functionality
    }
    if(e.keyCode == 40) // for doqn key
    {
        // implement focus functionality
    }
});
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the scrollbar dissapears making the content shift and then you'll have to calculate the offset somehow. I tried this, too complicated and unnecesary...

Answer (score -1):

The Best way to achive the same is to set overflow of the body to hidden

```
$("body").css("overflow", "hidden");
```

After the process just do the opposite

```
`$("body").css("overflow", "hidden");
```