# Prevent scroll event in jQuery

Tags: jquery, scroll

Is it possible to prevent scroll event in jQuery?

I've tried this code, but it didn't work.

```
$('*').scroll(function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
  event.preventDefault();
  return false;
})
```

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8485667/prevent-window-scroll-jquery?rq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well.. i worked with wrong event.
touchmove was exactly what i'm looked for. so

```
$('body').bind('touchmove', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 7):

You can disable scrolling within certain element areas using the following:

```
$("element,element2").bind("touchmove",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just set the `body` CSS to disable the scroll.

```
body {    
   overflow: hidden; 
}
```

Comment: thanks, it would work but not in my case..
i'm looking for something like to catch "keycode" or "scroll" event and pervent this.  
and i have to do this on mobile devise "Samsung", any ideas?