# Trouble with sliding tabs on site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello i have a trouble with my site http://bg.ddd-1.com/#/home i am using a one page layout and a scrolling jquery to emulate different pages with the ability to change scrolls/pages via a mouse scroll however my client doesn't like this function and wants me to remove it however i don't know how.I tried few mouse-scroll disabling scripts and one jquery hoever either i am not using them properly or they don't work after all its not that the page itself its scrolling but the emulated tabs. I would be gratefull if you guys will be able to help me

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent scroll event in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11185522/prevent-scroll-event-in-jquery)

Comment: You're loading jQuery twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you build a car with 5 wheels, and you decide that you only need 4, you don't encase the fifth wheel in concrete to disable it. You remove the wheel.

Here you're seeing behavior from a plugin that occurs not just on mousewheel, but with up and down arrows as well. You need to remove some of what's in script.js. In particular, code which references `.content_shifter`.

Alternatively, remove the `content_shifter` class from all elements where it occurs in your page markup.

Comment: He wanted to disable scroll-wheel functionality.  I provided a way to do that.  If you want to spend the time investigating his code to provide a more appropriate and efficient answer, that's fine, as a matter of fact it's great, but no need to downvote my answer (which does accomplish what he requested) and post a snide remark.

Though overall I do agree with you, and it is a good analogy. :)

Comment: Where did I post a snide remark? My analogy is a response to the OP mentioning that he had tried using scripts to disable scroll. It's nothing personal. Your answer is a wrong approach, IMO. Sure, it works, but that's not enough to make it a good answer.