# Disabling <a href=""> inside a <div> using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Am trying to disable a hyperlink present inside a div tag using Jquery, i used the below codes, which are not helpful.

**JQuery - 1.7v**

**html Code -**

```
<div id="content">TESTING PURPOSE <(a)> href="/test/">Click Here <(a)> End </div>
```

**jQuery - JS**

```
$('#content').find("*").prop("disabled", true);

$('#content').prop("disabled", true);
```

Comment: There is no disabled property for Anchor element, you could cancel the click of those as @dystroy answered

Comment: I reformatted your question. Please have a look at the difference (and at the edit help).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this :

```
$('#content a').click(function(){ return false });
```

Returning `false` from the click event handler prevents the default behavior (following the link).

If you may have more than one link but you want to disable only this one, you may be more specific in your selector :

```
$('#content a[href="/test/"]').click(function(){ return false });
```

Comment: I liked this approach, less code that do more and not hurts the legibility the better (IMHO)

Comment: @RobSchmuecker You might need to read [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) : *"Returning false from a handler is equivalent to calling both .preventDefault() and .stopPropagation() on the event object."*

Answer (score 2):

Use *preventDefault* to disable the default behavior of a link.

**Here is a little Code snippet:**

```
$('#content a').click(function(e) {
  // stop/prevent default behavior
  e.preventDefault();

  // do other stuff...
  // e.g. alert('Link is deactivated');
});
```

**[Here is  a little jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/XtXRH/)**

[Difference between *e.preventDefault* and *return false*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false)

Source: [Stackoverflow - jquery link tag enable disable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169625/jquery-link-tag-enable-disable)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this, just give div name of that anchor tag with remove function.

```
$('.div_name a').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#content a').click(function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.modal-body a').css({"pointer-events":"none"});
```