# jquery - Activate and deactivate hyperlink

Tags: jquery, tags, anchor

Please can you suggest some sample code on how to activate and deactivate a hyperlink on clicking it.

I tried the following, but no result

1) `$("a#click").onclick = function() { return false; }`

2) `$("a#click").attr ('href', '#');`

3)

```
$(function(){
  $("#disabled a").click(function () { 
    $(this).fadeTo("fast", .5).removeAttr("href"); 
  });
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to enable or disable anchor tag using jquery ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164635/how-to-enable-or-disable-anchor-tag-using-jquery)

Answer (score 3):

`$("a#click").click(function() { return false; });`

With this code, any clicks on the link will have no effect.  Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 3):

i would do it with a css class...
if a hyperlink needs to be disabled you toggle its class "disabled" to on.

this gives you the ability to style  a.disabled with a different style (cursor, color...)

and in the click event you just check only to perform an action if the clicked link does not own the class 'disabled'

```
$('a').bind('click', function(){
  if($(this).hasClass('disabled')) {
    // perform actions upon disabled... show the user he cannot click this link
    return false;
  } else {
    // perform actions for the click...
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about attaching functionality to an A-tag, but don't want the browser to process the HREF on it, there is a built-in jQuery method to do this:

```
$("a#click").click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();

// do stuff here 
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

My possible guess is

```
$('a').attr('disabled','disabled');
```

Let us know if it helps..

Comment: this will not work, according to http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-87355129 the disabled attribute on an anchor tag can only be used to trigger stylesheets.
 -- quote: disabled (of type boolean)
    Enables/disables the link. This is currently only used for style sheet links, and may be used to activate or deactivate style sheets. --