# How to enable html elements

Tags: jquery

I am using the following code to disable the anchor tag.Can anyone tell me how to enable it using jquery.

Code:

```
  $("#rightt").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

Geetha

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164635/how-to-enable-or-disable-anchor-tag-using-jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You [remove](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) the attribute:

```
$("#rightt").removeAttr("disabled");
```