# jQuery disable anchor tag bootstrap button onClick

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

**I want to disable my bootstrap button on-click** using Javascript, to prevent a double-click in order to avoid DbContext threading issues.

```
<a type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="BackBtn" asp-area="" asp-controller="PageStuff" asp-action="PageStuff" asp-route-culture="@CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name">@_loc[Model.BackButton]</a>
```

This works as expected and hides the button:

```
$("#BackBtn").on("click", function () {
    document.getElementById("BackBtn").style.display = "none";
});
```

This does **not** disable the button, but works elsewhere in my app for other elements:

```
$("#BackBtn").on("click", function () {
    document.getElementById("BackBtn").disabled = true;
});
```

I have also tried using `document.getElementById("BackBtn").unbind("click");` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6057595/disable-anchor-onclick).

And this `document.getElementById("BackBtn").prop("disabled", true);`

and this `$("#BackBtn").prop("disabled", "disabled");`

and this `$('BackBtn').prop("disabled", true);`

and this `document.getElementById("BackBtn").attr("disabled", "disabled");`

and this `$("#values:BackBtn").attr("disabled", true);`

and this `$("#BackBtn").attr("disabled", true);`

and this `$('BackBtn').attr('readonly', true);`

and this `[...document.querySelectorAll('BackBtn')].map(e => e.disabled = true);`

and various other variations.

**Any ideas how I can get the  button to disable on click?** Does 'disabled' even exist for an anchor tag of type="button" ? Im starting to think there is no such property.

Comment: `<a button` ? is that an a tag or a button or a typo?

Comment: It was a typo. Edited the question to remove it.

Comment: done check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `disabled` attribute works only on `button`, for anchor tag you can use `pointer-events: none;`

```js
$("#BackBtn").on("click", function() {
  $(this).css('pointer-events', 'none')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="BackBtn" asp-area="" asp-controller="PageStuff" asp-action="PageStuff" asp-route-culture="@CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name" href="#">Dsiable me</a>
```