# How do I disable/enable anchor in GWT?

Tags: gwt, mvp4g

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to enable or disable an anchor using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164635/how-to-enable-or-disable-an-anchor-using-jquery)

I'm having a hard time disabling the anchor. I've read that  there's an existing bug with Anchor.SetEnabled.

`anchor().setEnabled(false)` does not work due to browser constraints. However, is there another way to disable/enable the link?

Comment: Why is this tagged as mvp4g?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```java
// to disable the anchor
disabled = anchor.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
      event.preventDefault();
   }
});

// to re-enable it.
disabled.removeHandler();
```

Comment: `clickListener` doesn't prevent `onHistroryChange()` event which is responsible for adding a history token.

Comment: The question is about `Anchor`, not `Hyperlink` or `InlineHyperlink`. Note how `addClickHandler` in `Hyperlink` is deprecated and suggests using an `Anchor` and calling `History.newItem` by yourself if you want to "process the click before the history token is set".

Answer (score 0):

You can for example change [href](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.4/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Anchor.html#setHref%28java.lang.String%29), or make onClick events no-ops.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. the most suitable solution for me was to download the custom Anchor class given in the end of this [issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=2889) and use it instead of the GWT Anchor. It work from the first try !