# Prevent link <a> without href from clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to enable or disable an anchor using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164635/how-to-enable-or-disable-an-anchor-using-jquery)

I have this:

```
<a onclick="javascript:btnSave_onclick();" class="button">Save</a>
```

Basically, the link is acting like a button.

However, there are some conditions when I need to make it disabled. How to do this?

Comment: Give the conditions to an `if` statement in your `btnSave_onclick` function.

Comment: @amnotiam But then the link should be clicked. I want it not to be able to be clicked.

Comment: Only way to prevent a user from clicking a link is to hide or remove it.

Comment: Are you actually asking how to remove the onclick handler ?

Comment: @amnotiam Hmm I gues so. How to do it with code?

Comment: Assuming you have a reference to the element, you can simply do `el.onclick = null`, or `el.removeAttribute('onclick')` should also work.

Comment: See the first comment from Kshitij Mehta

Comment: @mdi: The link in the first comment doesn't provide a solution for what OP wants. `e.preventDefault()` won't prevent the `onclick`, and OP has stated in the comments that the function shouldn't run at all.

Comment: I was thinking of removing the inline JS and putting it in an external function, then using preventdefault. Or (but it's very ugly), a CSS transparent layer preventing the click.

Comment: @mdi: It's certainly an option to get rid of the inline handler, but the `preventDefault` still won't have any effect. That just prevents the `href` from being followed. A transparent layer is certainly valid, but I agree that it's a little ugly.

Comment: And maybe pointer-events: none in CSS ? Not sure about the browser support.

Comment: @mdi: Interesting, I hadn't heard of pointer-events, but according to [this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/pointer-events) it's primarily meant for SVG, and isn't yet standardized under CSS.

Comment: Yes, and according to your link, it won't work on IE and Opera. Duh.

Answer (score -1):

Any reason you're not just using a button instead? In that case you could just use

```
document.getElementById('button').disabled = true;
```

You would have to set an id for the button also

Comment: Why didn't you write this as a comment? It certainly doesn't provide a solution to the question "how to prevent LINK from clicking?".

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question.

Comment: It's still a very fair point. If it doesn't look or behave like a link, well don't make it a link. In this case, it seems like a button would have been more suitable.

Comment: Didn't mean to offend anyone here... If the anchor isn't pointing somewhere, it could be a button in which case dealing with disabling it in js is quite straightforward.