# disable anchor tag using Jquery

Tags: jquery, image, anchor

I have a image associated with the anchor tag, once the user clicks the image a popup loads. I want to disable this anchor tag.

The html code looks like:

```
<a href="#" class="openModalLink">
<img style="vertical-align: middle; border: none" width="9%" alt="" id="imgmap" class="zoom" /></a>
```

I have tried the below codes but doesn't seem to work

```
 $(".openModalLink").off("click");
 $(".openModalLink").attr("disabled", true);
 $(".openModalLink").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

Thanks for the replies

Comment: :) This exact question is asked many times bruv: see duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164635/how-to-enable-or-disable-an-anchor-using-jquery

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could do this

```
$('.openModalLink').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Also refer [docs](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

**EDIT:**

To enable and disable anchor tag

```
function disabler(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
}

$('#enable').click(function(){
    $('.openModalLink').unbind('click',disabler);
});
$('#disable').click(function(){
    $('.openModalLink').bind('click',disabler);
});
​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/dhnAj/3/)**

**EDIT 2:**

As of jquery 1.7 `.on()` and `.off()` are preferred over bind and unbind to attach and remove event handlers on elements

```
$('#enable').click(function() {
    $('body').off('click', '.openModalLink', disabler);
});
$('#disable').click(function() {
    $('body').on('click', '.openModalLink', disabler);
});​
```