# How to disable jquery ui button (when <a> tag turn to button)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I use `Jquery UI 1.9.2` to convert an `<a>` tag into a button.
But disabling newly created button only affect appearance(good) and mouse click still works(bad).
I'm using `firefox 32`.
Here is my snippet:

```
<a href="#" onclick="alert('hi');">click me if enabled</a>
<script>
    $('a').button({disabled:true});
</script>
```

Is this behavior related to nature of `<a>` tag and cannot be addressed by `jquery UI` tools and options?
How can i suppress `onClick` anyway?

Comment: instead of the onclick attribute use jQuery event handlers - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/h2085ycd/1/

Comment: Perhaps, this link can help you. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19006299/jquery-disable-and-enable-an-anchor-tag-based-on-condition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19006299/jquery-disable-and-enable-an-anchor-tag-based-on-condition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this only works for `<button>` elements.

See my jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/xBB5x/9544/

You have to remove the onclick for the `a` to stop working like:

```
$("a").attr('onclick', '')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xBB5x/9545/

Comment: Yes i know. but assume for some reason i have to use <a> tag