# Check for disabled button not working

Tags: javascript

I have the following statically programmed button:

```
<a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="javascript:void(0)" id="action" disabled="disabled">
```

And want to check if the button is disabled so I can set the preventDefault() because, if it is not set to disabled (by another function) the button must do its work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){    

 // IF ACTION BUTTON IS DISABLED, DISABLE DROPDOWN CLICK
 if ($('#action').is(':disabled')) {
 alert("inside if");
  event.preventDefault();
  return false; 
 };
});
</script>
```

But it never throws me the alert. I can see with inspect element the button has disabled="disabled" attribute so it should work. What am I doing wrong?

**note:** I am using jQuery, so if that is applicable then please point out :)

Comment: The `:disabled` is a css selector. Try using `$('#action').attr('disabled')`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164635/how-to-enable-or-disable-an-anchor-using-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 if ($('#action').prop('disabled', true)) {
     alert("inside if");
     event.preventDefault();
     return false; 
 };
```

Comment: oh i thought there is written "it does not work" sorry ^_^ sleeping zzzz

Comment: Ahh, so the :disabled checks the css. Now I understand :) It works with .prop

Comment: well, :disabled is a psuedo element! you can use for styling it just like this `input:disabled { border:1px solid #a898a2; }` but not like this as you done above see more on is() function jQuery! google it!

Comment: ah free all the time for you buddy :)