# .prop disable is not working in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: jquery, disable-link

We are using jquery-1.7.1 and are trying to hide a button in asp.net. The button is a linkbutton control. The code we are using is as follows

```
function checkDisabledButton(btn){
    var mbtn = $('#' + btn)
    mbtn.prop('disabled', true);
};
```

the button gets disabled in IE but Chrome and Firefox is does not get disabled.  I've seen a lot of post about it.. but most of those talk about needing jQuery 1.7.. which we are already using.  Was hoping someone could lend a hand.

After looking at the reponses
I've been looking into changing to a asp:button which gets rendered as an input type=submit.  What i really want is to be able to call a function to do the disable of the control.  In that way i can use the same function for multipal buttons and multipal pages.  I've still not got it working, but with that in mind.. I was hoping someone could continue with the help.  Here is the button control being called

```
<asp:Button ID="lbApprove" runat="server" CssClass="ButtonPrimary button" Text="Approve" OnClientClick="return tryIt(this, 'PROCESSING');"/>
```

The tryIt changes the text of the button once clicked to whatever i pass in (in this case 'PROCESSING').  Again.. i want the button to only be clickable once.  I've looked at the .one and also the .on and .off but haven't had any luck just yet. I am not posting any code at this point as it's just try's so far...

Here is the latest and at first attempt appears to work.  It's not jQuery.. but might be a start. It disables the button before page postback happens. It comes from this article. Got to have a starting point right :)

http://aspsnippets.com/Articles/Disable-Button-before-Page-PostBack-in-ASP.Net.aspx

Comment: mind providing the html as well? or whipping up a jsFiddle?

Comment: The issue is elsewhere. Your posted JavaScript works. The method, .prop(), was added in [1.6](http://api.jquery.com/category/version/1.6/)

Answer (score 3):

If it's a link button, then it renders as an anchor.  The `disabled` attribute isn't a standard attribute for anchors.  The fact that IE works is nonstandard/unspecified behavior.

As proof, see this jsfiddle where I'm setting disabled not through jquery but through the html attribute http://jsfiddle.net/5htFh/.  Note in FF it still follows.  So it's not jquery failing you in anyway; it's the fact that `disabled` just isn't an option for anchors under the html4 spec.

See this SO thread on how others recommend doing this with anchors: [How to enable or disable an anchor using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164635/how-to-enable-or-disable-an-anchor-using-jquery)