# Want to make inactive hyperlink

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I have problem in hide and show the div element.
In this scenario when user click on the year  the respect content is shown.
**Problem** I want to inactive hyperlinking on respective year when it is opened.
The script and html is below;
for this I have tried `.preventDefault().` but not got any success:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
      $(document).ready(function() {
         $("div.new:gt(0)").hide();// to hide all div except for the first one
         $("div[name=arrow]:eq(0)").hide();
         // $("div.nhide:gt(0)").hide(); 
          // $("a[name=new]").hide();
         $("a[name=new]").hide();
         $('#content a').click(function(selected) {

            var getID = $(this).attr("id"); 
            var value=  $(this).html(); 
           
            if( value == '&lt;&lt; Hide')
            {
                // $("#" + getID + "arrow").hide();
                $("a[name=new]").hide();
                $("#" + getID + "_info" ).slideUp('slow');
                $("div[name=arrow]").show();
                $("div.new").hide(); 
                $(this).hide();
                // var getOldId=getID;
                // $("#" + getID ).html('&lt;&lt; Hide').hide(); 
            }
            if($("a[name=show]"))  
            {
                // $("div.new:eq(0)").slideUp()
                $("div.new").hide(); 
                $("div[name=arrow]").show();
                $("a[name=new]").hide();
                $("#news" + getID + "arrow").hide();
                $("#news" + getID + "_info" ).slideDown();
                
                $("#news" + getID ).html('&lt;&lt; Hide').slideDown(); 
            } 
            
        });  
    });  
</script>
```

The html code is below:

```
<div id="content">
<div class="news_year">
 <a href="#" name="show"  id="2012">
   <div style="float:left;" name="year" id="news2012year">**2012** </div>
   <div style="float:left;" name="arrow" id="news2012arrow">&gt;&gt;</div>
 </a>
    </div> 
        
 <div class="new" id="news2012_info">
   <div class="news">
      <div class="news_left">News for 2012</div>
   </div>
    <div class="nhide" ><a href="#" class="new" name="new" id="news2012">&lt;&lt; Hide</a>  </div>
  </div>
<div id="content">
<div class="news_year">
 <a href="#" name="show"  id="2011">
   <div style="float:left;" name="year" id="news2012year">2012 </div>
   <div style="float:left;" name="arrow" id="news2012arrow">&gt;&gt;</div>
 </a>
    </div> 
        
 <div class="new" id="news2011_info">
   <div class="news">
      <div class="news_left">News for 2011</div>
   </div>
    <div class="nhide" ><a href="#" class="new" name="new" id="news2011">&lt;&lt; Hide</a>  </div>
  </div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ethagnawl/sn4aG/)

Answer (score 0):

if i am understanding your problem,
  event.preventDefault(); not works with all browser so if you are using other browser like IE
then use event.returnValue = false; instead of that.so you can detect your browser using javascript  as

var appname = window.navigator.appName;

Answer (score 0):

This is what I'm currently using in my projects to "disable" an anchor tag

Disabling the anchor:

- Remove `href` attribute
- Change the opacity for added effect

---

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("a").click(function () { 
                $(this).fadeTo("fast", .5).removeAttr("href"); 
            });
        });
</script>
```

Enabling the anchor:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").click(function () { 
        $(this).fadeIn("fast").attr("href", "http://whatever.com/wherever.html"); 
    });
});
```

Original code can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3736724/973578)

Answer (score 0):

Surround the code inside of the click function with an `if` statement checking to see if a variable is true or false. If it is false, it won't run the code, meaning the link is effectively inactive. Try this..

```
var isActive = true;
if (isActive) {
    // Your code here
}
// The place where you want to de-activate the link
isActive = false;
```

You could also consider changing the link colour to a grey to signify that it is inactive.

**Edit**
Just realised that you want to have multiple links being disabled.. the code above will disable all of them. Try the code below (put the `if` around the code in the click function)

```
if(!$(this).hasClass("disabled")) {
    // Your code here
}

// The place where you want to de-activate the link
$("#linkid").addClass("disabled");

// To re-enable a link
$("#linkid").removeClass("disabled");

// You can even toggle the link from disabled and non-disabled!
$("#linkid").toggleClass("disabled");
```

Then in your CSS you could have a declaration like this:

```
.disabled:link {
    color:#999;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a class called 'shown' to your wrapper element when expanding your element and remove it when hiding it. Use `.hasClass('shown')` to ensure the inappropriate conditional is never executed.