# disabling a tag with input type=button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, I have an  tag that looks like:

```
<a id="createBtn" class="btn" title="" type="button">
<b>+</b>
Create New
</a>
```

Sometimes, we want it active, sometimes not.  I've tried multiple ways to disable it, adding the disabled class, adding the property disabled, attempting to remove the type attribute (which I learned you cannot do), binding it to a function that prevents the default behavior, and using jquery's `.bind('click', false)`, but nothing seems to work.

I was wondering what js or jquery things I can to do this  tag in order to disable it.  It gets grayed out like it's disabled, but it still has the action tied to it which is a backbone

Here's some, not all of the things that I tried:

```
            this.$('#createBtn').addClass('disabled');
            this.$('#createBtn').attr('type', 'button');
            this.$('#createBtn').bind('click', false);


        } else {
            this.$('#createBtn').removeAttr('type');
            this.$('#createBtn').removeClass('disabled');
```

The #createBtn is tied to an event that updates the UI that is created in the initialize method of this backbone view.

```
"click #createBtn": "renderNewTemplate",
```

Comment: What happens when the anchor is clicked - is this submitting a form?

Comment: @Evan it updates the UI by adding a new div on the page.

Comment: There is no `href` attribute that's causing this? I see no `action` as you mentioned, so I'm confused in that regard.

Comment: @Evan Sorry, I should have added that this is a backbone view.  I'm just getting started working with backbone and I didn't realize it at first what was happening.  I added that snipped to my original question.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I go about disabling `anchor` tags (`<a>`):

Disable the tag by removing its `href` attribute, and decreasing its `opacity` for an added effect:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#createBtn").click(function () { 
        $(this).fadeTo("fast", .5).removeAttr("href"); 
    });
});
```

And enabling the anchor:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#createBtn").click(function () { 
        $(this).fadeIn("fast").attr("href", "original href here"); 
    });
});
```

Original answer can be found here - I'm just recycling it as I use this in all of my projects that requires a disabling of an anchor tag

[How to enable or disable an anchor using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164635/how-to-enable-or-disable-an-anchor-using-jquery)