# Bouncing submenu jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I´m doing a menu that every item has it´s submenu. this is the markup:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="show_submenu(this)">TITLE 1</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)">sub1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)">sub2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">TITLE 2</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)">sub1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)">sub2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">TITLE 3</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">TITLE 4</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

css

```
.submenu{display:none}
```

script

```
function show_submenu(that) {
    $('ul.submenu').slideUp();
    $(that).next('ul.submenu:first').slideDown();
}
```

The problem I have is that if I click over an item, it slides down it´s submenu, **BUT if I click over it again**, it slidesup and slidesdown again it´s submenu, **which is already opened**... kind of weird effect for the user... any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: You're using jQuery... so there's no need for all those `href="javascript:void(0)"`.

Comment: I read it´s necessary to avoid issues with IE or something...

Comment: The main point of using a JavaScript framework like jQuery is to minimize any browser specific issues.  You can use `href="#"` and then investigate how to properly implement [jQuery's  `event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) within your jQuery code.

Comment: Yeah, in the article said it was better to use void(0) than the # you are saying... they discussed that :) sorry I don´t have the reference right now

Comment: I think you misunderstand.  Sure, all by itself, `void(0)` may be a better option than `#`.  However, it's not by itself.  [Using jQuery's `preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) as I recommended, there is no issue with `href="#"` in any browser.  See:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/1164654/594235

Comment: ok, I see. thank you! will use it that way then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check whether the existing submenu is visible already.  If it is, you don't want to slide it down again.

```
var $submenu = $(that).next('ul.submenu:first'),
    viz = $submenu.is(":visible");
    $('ul.submenu').slideUp();
if (!viz) {
    $(that).next('ul.submenu:first').slideDown();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/zep6H/

Answer (score 0):

use toggle in jquery

```
$('#foo').toggle(showOrHide);
```

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Answer (score 0):

It's doing exactly what you coded it to do. Instead, use [`.slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/);

```
function show_submenu(that){
    $(that).next('ul.submenu:first').slideToggle();
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/RpBmj/)**

Answer (score 0):

this should help

```
function show_submenu(that){
if(!$(that).next('ul.submenu:first').is(":visible")){
        $('ul.submenu').slideUp();
        $(that).next('ul.submenu:first').slideDown();
}
    }
```