# Making a Twitter Bootstrap button (link) disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

What's the real and working way to make a twitter bootstrap button (which is a **LINK**) disabled? They mostly suggest that it is:

```
$("#my_btn").prop("disabled", true); //1
//or
$("#my_btn").attr("disabled", true); //2
```

But this does **NOT** work. What does work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A link doesn't actually have a `disabled` attribute.

Instead, you'll need to add the `.disabled` css class.

```
$("#my_btn").addClass("disabled");
```

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons-disabled (The section on *Anchor element*)

As per the discussion below, you should note that this isn't a sure-fire way of actually disabling the link in all browsers. It only uses CSS's `pointer-events: none`, which isn't as robust as the `disabled` attribute on a `<button>` element.

Comment: and yet you'll be able to click it. that's not disabling.

Comment: look here on how to disable a link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164635/how-to-enable-or-disable-an-anchor-using-jquery

Comment: Actually, the bootstrap `disabled` class adds `pointer-events: none;`, which will stop the link from being clicked.

Comment: There is no _cross-browser_ built-in Bootstrap way of disabling a link. (http://caniuse.com/pointer-events)

Comment: To extend this, you could leverage the `disabled` class you added: `$('a.disabled').on('click', function(e){ e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation(); });`

Answer (score 1):

What version of jQuery you using? If you need disable a link, you can add a CSS class `.disabled` to that link with this jQuery command:

```
$("#my_btn").addClass("disabled");
```

This code below is working for **INPUT** only

**jQuery 1.6+**

```
$("input").prop('disabled', true);
$("input").prop('disabled', false);
```

**jQuery 1.5 and below**

```
$("input").attr('disabled','disabled');
$("input").removeAttr('disabled');
```

**In any version of jQuery**

```
// assuming an event handler thus 'this'
this.disabled = true;
```

You can check this thread: [Disable/enable an input with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414365/how-to-disable-enable-an-input-with-jquery) and here you will find your answer I hope :)

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple!

just add the **disabled** class.
Disabled:

```
<button class="btn btn-default disabled">Text</button>
```

Non disabled:

```
  <button class="btn btn-default">Text</button>
```