# jQuery: How to hide and show the href?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to hide the `href` without hiding the whole anchor tag?

```
<a href="somelinks">Click Me</a>
```

The reason I need this is because I'd need to hide and show it based on desktop and mobile view controlled by JS.

Something like `$('a').attr('href').hide();` won't work

**Edit**:
I need to 'hide' the href so I can 'show' it where I need to. Removing the `href` will not restore it.

Comment: remove only possible

Comment: Simply to use `$('a').on('click',function(){return false;});` should work

Comment: Duplicate question: [How to enable or disable an anchor using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164635/how-to-enable-or-disable-an-anchor-using-jquery)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to hide the `href` but still want it to redirect when clicked, use this.

Get the URL and put it in `data` attribute. Then remove the `href` attribute.

```
$('a').each(function() {
    $(this).data('href', $(this).attr('href')).removeAttr('href');
});
```

When clicked on `anchor`, get the URL from `data` attribute and redirect.

```
$('a').on('click', function() {
    window.location.href = $(this).data('href');
});
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [removeAttr()](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/):

```js
$('a').removeAttr('href');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="somelinks">Click Me</a>
```

> **Description**: Remove an attribute from each element in the set of matched elements

Comment: You can not hide an attribute. You can only remove it. Alternative you can use `#` as value.

Comment: Check also here a solution I create [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AlexChariz/rzoLux66/)

Comment: Agree with Alex Char . @Tushar indirectly you do the same thing.

Comment: @Hardy Yes but the `href` is hidden for the links

Answer (score 1):

But what if You want to restore href? From where will You get it?

```
<div class="some-container">
    <a href="somelinks">Click Me</a>
    <a href="somelinks2">Click Me</a>
</div>

function hideHrefs(selector) {
    $(selector).each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        var href = $this.attr('href');
        $this.attr('href', '').data('href', href);
    });
}

function restoreHref($element) {
    var href = $element.data('href');
    $element.attr('href', href);
}

hideHrefs('.some-container a'); // hides all hrefs from links in container element
restoreHref($('.some-container a:first'));  // restores href for dedicated element
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that when you don't want the href you do something like this

```
$($.find("a")).attr("href", "#")
```

Comment: What is `$($.find("a"))` ?

Comment: $.find("a") will get you all the anchor tags you can give your specific selector here. [More](https://api.jquery.com/find/)



$($.find("a")).attr("href", "#") //to all the anchors tags returned by find make the href as "#"