# How to stop default link click behavior with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, click, jquery-events

I have a link on a web page.  When a user clicks it, a widget on the page should update.  However, I am doing something, because the default functionality (navigating to a different page) occurs before the event fires.

This is what the link looks like:

```
<a href="store/cart/" class="update-cart">Update Cart</a>
```

This is what the jQuery looks like:

```
$('.update-cart').click(function(e) { 
  e.stopPropagation(); 
  updateCartWidget(); 
});
```

What is the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery disable a link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/970388/jquery-disable-a-link)

Answer (score 146, accepted):

```
e.preventDefault();
```

from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault

> Cancels the event if it is cancelable,
>   without stopping further propagation
>   of the event.

Comment: Thanks, I had `stopPropagation` and `preventDefault` confused

Answer (score 37):

```
$('.update-cart').click(function(e) {
    updateCartWidget();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
});

$('.update-cart').click(function() {
    updateCartWidget();
    return false;
});
```

The following methods achieve the exact same thing.

Comment: Why do I need to call `stopPropagation()` and `preventDefault()`?

Comment: Look at Jonathons answer, he explains what each function does. But basically, to make sure the click you just handled isn't handled by someone else later.

Answer (score 31):

You want `e.preventDefault()` to prevent the default functionality from occurring.

Or have `return false` from your method.

`preventDefault` prevents the default functionality and `stopPropagation` prevents the event from bubbling up to container elements.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `e.preventDefault();` instead of `e.stopPropagation();`

Answer (score 1):

This code strip all event listeners

```
var old_element=document.getElementsByClassName(".update-cart");    
var new_element = old_element.cloneNode(true);
old_element.parentNode.replaceChild(new_element, old_element);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just wasted an hour on this.  I tried everything - it turned out (and I can hardly believe this) that giving my cancel button and element id of cancel meant that any attempt to prevent event propagation would fail!  I guess an HTML page must treat this as someone pressing ESC?