# How to avoid from scroll to top when opening bootstrap tabs

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to open specific bootstrap tab from clicking on an external link.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
  <li><a href="#message" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">Contents</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="message">Contents</div>
</div>

// Out side link which is place on different page: 
<a href="index.php?p=edit-profile#profile">Profile Link From Outside</a>
```

This is how I tried it using jquery:

```
// Javascript to enable link to tab
var url = document.location.toString();
if (url.match('#')) {
    $('.nav-tabs a[href=#'+url.split('#')[1]+']').tab('show') ;
} 

// Change hash for page-reload
$('.nav-tabs a').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    window.location.hash = e.target.hash;
})
```

This is opening my tabs correctly. But my problem is when it open page scroll to the top of the page. Is there a way to avoid from this problem?

I tied it with `.scrollTop();` but I couldn't figure it out.

After adding `.scrollTop();` my code lookk like this.

```
// Javascript to enable link to tab
var url = document.location.toString();
if (url.match('#')) {
    $('.nav-tabs a[href=#'+url.split('#')[1]+']').tab('show') ;
} 

// Change hash for page-reload
$('.nav-tabs a').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    window.location.hash = e.target.hash;
    $('html,body').scrollTop(300);
});
```

Any idea would be highly appreciated. 
Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps it scrolls up to the tab? If that is the case you may change the id with class or prevent the default behaviour of the links.

Comment: Try adding `e.preventDefault();` on `shown.bs.tab` event.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to stop default link click behavior with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5632031/how-to-stop-default-link-click-behavior-with-jquery)

Comment: @D4V1D. I checked it.. but problem is still same.

Comment: updated code - ` $('.nav-tabs a').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
     window.location.hash = e.target.hash;
     $('html,body').scrollTop(300);
 });`

Comment: my url is like this - `index.php?p=edit-profile#profile` so when page is reloading tabs display top of the browser window.

Answer (score 1):

I found that for Firefox I had to also add **e.stopImmediatePropagation()**

```
$('.nav-tabs li a').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  $(this).tab('show');
});
```

Hope this helps