# How to load Layout without refreshing in Liferay Theme?

Tags: jquery, ajax, liferay, liferay-6

I want to update the contents/portlets of my [pages](https://www.liferay.com/it/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Layout), without reloading the whole page.

[image]

I tried using jQuery `.load()` in *navigation.ftl*:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("nav#navigation ul li a").click(function(){
            var page = $(this).attr("href");
            $("#content").load(page);
        });
    });
</script>
```

I added `e.preventDefault()` to prevent the default functionality from occurring as suggested by *Sudakatux* and It works but this does not resolve my problem, because the entire page (including head and body) is wrapped inside the `div#content` each time I click on a menu (see the screenshot below).

[image: The page is repeated inside the div #content]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop default link click behavior with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5632031/how-to-stop-default-link-click-behavior-with-jquery)

Answer (score 4):

This is not a Liferay question. You are missing the `preventDefault()` since you are using a link:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("nav#navigation ul li a").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault(); //You are missing this line
            var page = $(this).attr("href");
            $("#content").load(page);
        });
    });
</script>
```

If you used a button (not submit) this wouldnt happen. Meaning is not really 'Liferay's fault'

Comment: Thank you so much! it works, but the entire page (including head and body) is wrapped inside the `div#content`, so when I click on a menu I get two headers and two footers.

Comment: thats because you are loading the entire page. not the portlet jsp. what you need is the url of the jsp you can get that by doing something like this ```<portlet:renderURL var ="onCancelURL "><portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/jsp/managePrinter.jsp" /></portlet:renderURL>```  and then in a javascript delcare a var with its value ```var p = '<%= onCancelURL %>' ``` then load in ```$('#content').load(p)``` hope it helps