# HTML form get submitted empty

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code, with which i try to dynamically pass my arguments between pages

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function buildAndSubmitForm(index){
        <?  $args = 't='.$team.'&s='.$season.'&l='.$league.'&f='.$flag;
            $inputs = '';
            foreach($games as $game)
                $inputs .= '<input type="checkbox" name="games[]" id="games[]" value="'.$game.'" checked="checked" />';
        ?>
        var form = '<?='<form name="myForm" id="myForm" action="scr'?>';
        form = form.concat(index);
        form = form.concat('<?='.php?'.$args.'" method="post">'.$inputs.'</form>'?>');
        $('#formDiv').html(form);
        $('#myForm'.concat(index)).submit();
    }
</script>
<div style="display: inline">
    <div name="formDiv" id="formDiv" style="display: none;"></div>
    <a href="#" onclick="buildAndSubmitForm('a')">Home Stats</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="buildAndSubmitForm('b')">Visit Stats</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="buildAndSubmitForm('c')">Wins VS Losses</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="buildAndSubmitForm('d')">Home VS Visit</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="buildAndSubmitForm('e')">Overall</a>
</div>
```

The problem is that when i click at a certain speed (click on a link, then as it is getting submitted (like a half a second - second later) I click another link), my form gets submitted empty to the second link I've clicked.
Why is this happening?

EDIT:
Tryed to do the following instead:

```
<div style="display: inline">
    <a href="<?php echo "scra.php?t=$team&s=$season&l=$league&f=$flag"; foreach($games as $game) {echo "&game=$game"; }?>" >Home Stats</a>
    <a href="<?php echo "scrb.php?t=$team&s=$season&l=$league&f=$flag"; foreach($games as $game) {echo "&game=$game"; }?>" >Visit Stats</a>
    <a href="<?php echo "scrc.php?t=$team&s=$season&l=$league&f=$flag"; foreach($games as $game) {echo "&game=$game"; }?>" >Wins VS Losses</a>
    <a href="<?php echo "scrd.php?t=$team&s=$season&l=$league&f=$flag"; foreach($games as $game) {echo "&game=$game"; }?>" >Home VS Visit</a>
    <a href="<?php echo "scre.php?t=$team&s=$season&l=$league&f=$flag"; foreach($games as $game) {echo "&game=$game"; }?>" >Overall</a>
</div>
```

EDIT2:
None of the solutions work yet.

Comment: Don't rely on short open tags and what is this? `var form = '<?='<form name="myForm" id="myForm" action="scr'?>';` And why do you build your form using JavaScript? Why not directly in PHP?

Comment: Regarding edit: what's the output? Can you show us the source as it is sent to the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to prevent double-clicks, you **need** to disable the link after it's been clicked.  Here is a previous SO question that provides an jQuery solution to disabling links:

[jQuery disable a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970388/jquery-disable-a-link)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using Javascript to concatenate text that was generated via PHP? Why not simply do:

```
<?php

$form = <<<EOL
<form name="myForm" id="myForm" action="scr.php?{$args}" method="post">{$inputs}</form>
EOL;

?>

<script ....>

var form = <?php echo json_encode($form) ?>;
$('#formDiv').html(form);

etc...
```

As well, if ANYTHING in your `$args` or `$inputs` variables in PHP contain quotes (single or double), most likely you're generating invalid HTML which is breaking your `<form>` tag.

Comment: I am concatenating an index variable there. Look carefully.

Comment: @Vadik: Yes, I see. But you're using Javascript to generate a form tag based on data filled in by PHP. Why not have PHP generate the whole thing to start with? It's like using a hammer to hit a screwdriver to turn a screw.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use query string (GET parameter instead of POST)?

If it's because of the checkbox (checked games), you can simply pass em with different query string (&games=baseball&games=football...). Your variable will be an array.

This way you won't even need a form.

Comment: Didn't work, I am updating my question, tell me where am I wrong.

Comment: Another thing, isn't the url limited?

Comment: 1. What didn't work? 
2. Yep, but it's pretty high iirc.
3. Did you consider disabling your links after an onClick, so that multiple clicks is not possible?

Comment: if you use jquery... catch your click event with `$('a').onclick(function(){})` , have a var or something else checking if the form is submitting, and return false if you dont want it to work.... or just add a global var to your current script and check its value (`var isSubmitting = false; function buildAndSubmit(){ if (isSubmitting==true){return;}; isSubmitting==true; [...]`)