# How to disable a hyperlink using jquery

Tags: jquery, hyperlink

I have two hyperlinks on my page: `previous` and `next` which navigate to the previous and next pages respectively. I want to disable `previous` when I am at the first page and disable `next` when I am on the last page.

To try this out I used the following code (`showPage` is hardcoded here).

```
 $("#prevUp").click(function (event)
        {

         event.preventDefault();
        var showPage=0;
         if(showPage<=1)
         {
            $("a").removeAttr('href');
         }

   });
```

However this is not working. Would you please tell me how I can do this (I have already looked at previous solutions on this problem but could not find one that works for me).

**EDIT:**

look at http://jsfiddle.net/bhXbh/38/  I tried several solutions here but none are working.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery disable a link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/970388/jquery-disable-a-link)

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
$("a").attr('href', 'javascript:');
```

Comment: Alex Ackerman: its not working. look at jsfiddle.net/bhXbh/37

Comment: It performs all the javascript before you set the href attribute to 'javascript:', but it will not go to the link specified in the href, if it's there. Although I would agree that using 'disabled' attribute is better.

Answer (score 1):

try the below

```
$("a").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Comment: Or, `$("a").attr('disabled', true);`

Answer (score 1):

You can also try

```
$("a").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Svetlin Panayotov: check this, and tell me what i am doing wrong http://jsfiddle.net/bhXbh/37/

Answer (score 1):

Normally, by calling

```
event.preventDefault();
```

The browser doesn't load the page...

Answer (score 1):

Let us suppose u have total 10 pages. Update your pagination like when we click on page 10 , href value for next link would be javascript:void(0) and when we click on first page previous link href value will be javascript:void(0). And when your page loaded first time previoud link value will be same as javascript:void(0).
Use simple if else condition to check your page no. You can send your page no in querystring.

Answer (score 1):

please see below for the code that I think your looking for:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var currentPage = <current page here>
    var pageTotal = <total number of pages>

    if(currentPage<=1)$('#previous').attr('disabled','disabled');
    if(currentPage>=pageTotal)$('#next').attr('disabled','disabled');

});
```

May I suggest you do this in a server side language if your loading pages you simply do it all in a server side language and do it as the DOM is being sent to the client, as opposed to letting the DOM load client side and doing the necessary actions (seen above) because it will mean the user can, if they wanted to, fiddle with the buttons.

Answer (score 1):

```
jQElement.prop('disabled',true);
```

Comment: Please explain your code a bit more even if the answer is obvious (as is the case here)

Answer (score 0):

`$("a").attr('disabled', true);`

Comment: you are trying to do client side pagination?

Comment: then you can use any pagination plugin..why you are trying to re-invent the wheel :)

Comment: Vivek : may i know how can i use that