# Emulating left mouse button selection in IE8 (preventDefault)

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, selection

This is a follow up question to: [Can you emulate the left-mouse button selection in JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7254890/can-you-emulate-the-left-mouse-button-selection-in-jquery)

The solution works fine in IE9, Firefox and Chrome, but it IE8 still does the browser's default selection i.e. highlighting the text.

```
isMouseDown = false

$('body').mousedown(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent default behavior
    isMouseDown = true;
})
.mouseup(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent default behavior
    isMouseDown = false;
});

$(".div").live("mouseenter", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent default behavior
    if (isMouseDown) {
        $(this).toggleClass("selected");
    }
});
```

So I assume `e.preventDefault()` is not working. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution myself. You have to prevent the default in `mousemove` too:

```
// Because IE8 won't get it without this...
$(".module").mousemove(function (e) {
    if ($.browser.msie) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```