# Rails link_to - disable after click?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Like in topic - is there some option to remove action for

```
link_to
```

after click on it?

Comment: do you need to disable a link forever, or just until the action is done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you need to do this through Javascript.  When the link is clicked you can set a disabled attribute.  On subsequent clicks, you can then check for the attribute and if it is set, you can then use `e.preventDefault();` to prevent the link from being following.

See: [jQuery disable a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970388/jquery-disable-a-link)

If you're using something like Twitter Bootstrap, there are some more elegant options, via button loading states.

Comment: And to do the click, I think they can use a `:onclick => 'my_javascript_call();'` as a parameter to the `link_to`.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you're trying to do, you can probably finagle `link_to_if` and `link_to_unless` to get achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look of this, a good explation of this guy:

[How to disable HTML links](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10276157/1156207)

the right way to do it:

```
a {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```