# Disabling all <a> and <i> that are inside a div

Tags: jquery

For a site I'm doing, I have a feature where a user can hide or delete his posts. When a user hides or deletes his post, I change the div's background color (to make it look like its dead). However, I'd like to disable all the `<a></a>` and `<i></i>` that are inside them as well (make them un-clickable so he can no longer use them).

How can i do something like this using jquery?

It's much like what happens when you delete your own post here on `stackoverflow.com`, only thing is I need all the `<a></a>` and `<i></i>` disabled. The `<i>s` call a jquery function when clicked. That's why I need them disabled.

```
<div class="post user" id="EN001">
    <a href="/user/john">View other posts by John</a>
    <i class="icon-hide hide" data-hash="a4d8e82s8w2d2"></i> Hide your post
    <i class="icon-delete delete" data-hash="a4d8e82s8w2d2"></i> Delete your post
</div>

$('.hide,.delete').live('click', function() {
    // self. I fail here;
});
```

Comment: To disable a link, you might want to read this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/970388/jquery-disable-a-link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest and easiest way could be to show a semi-transparent overlay on the `div`.

***Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/DGek7/***

*Relevant CSS*:

```
div.post {
    position: relative;
}
div.disabled::before {
    content: '';
    background-color: rgba(128,128,128,0.5);
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
}
```

*Relevant JS*:

```
$('.hide, .delete').on('click', function() {
   $(this).parent().addClass("disabled");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the semi-transparent trick. This is exactly what I was trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

A very minimal and simple solution would be to disable pointer events while adding your prefered style:

CSS:

```
div.disabled {
   pointer-events: none;
   cursor: default;
   opacity: 0.5;
   background: #dddddd;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.hide, .delete').on('click', function() {
   $(this).parent().addClass("disabled");
});
```

Comment: This is a simpler and cleaner solution indeed.

Answer (score 0):

You could capture any clicks inside the div and stop them from propagating

```
$("#EN001").click(function (ev) {
  return false; // same as ev.preventDefault() + ev.stopPropagation()
});
```

Or you could prevent the default behavior on links (you will have to find a different way to disable the "i" elements, maybe add a "disabled" class and check for it on the other event handler

```
$("#EN001").on("click","a",function (ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
});
```