# Jquery: click on list item add class to another list item

Tags: jquery

Now I have two list:

```
<ul class="first">    
    <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li>  
    <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li>  
    <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li> 
</ul>

<ul class="second">    
    <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li>  
    <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li>  
    <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li> 
</ul>
```

I want result: when I click on e.g. ul.fist > li (second child) > a, disable click/redirect to link, but, add two different class one for ul.second li (first child), other for ul.second li (third child). If I click on  ul.fist > li (third child) the add class to ul.second li (first child) and ul.second li (fourth child), etc.

eg.

```
 <ul class="first">    
        <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li>  
        <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li> <<-- click there, disable link
        <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li>  
        <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li> 
    </ul>

    <ul class="second">    
        <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li>  <<-- add class firstclass 
        <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li>   <<-- add class secondclass
        <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li> 
    </ul>
```

Comment: This is a good try at a description for your problem but right now I don't understand the pattern. Since programming is basically all about patterns (unless you want to hard code every possible scenario), could you give us more information? Why is a link disabled and why are there classes added. Will every click on the first list disable the link there and add classes to 1st and 4th child of second? In case you have trouble explaining, write user stories.

Comment: Sorry for my english.
Link is not disabled, I want to disable cause I dont want to link to URL, I only want to add class to ul.second - its can be something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/970388/jquery-disable-a-link Clicking on ul.first list items I want to add class to ul.second list items but, for two items, always for first and, if i clicked in ul.first two first item, than in ul.second to second list item, if for second than for third, etc.