# disable pagination button in bulma not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, bulma

I have bulma pagination component like this:

```
<nav class="pagination">
   <a class="pagination-previous">Previous</a>
   <a class="pagination-next">Next page</a>
</nav>
```

my purpose is to disable pagination-next button via jquery using prop function:

```
$('.pagination-next').prop('disabled', true);
```

but is not working at all, did I do something wrong ? what is the problem with it

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing it to `.attr()` makes it work.
Like this `$('.pagination-next').attr('disabled', true);`

Referencing jQuery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/
*Description: Get the value of a property for the first element in the set of matched elements*

so the `.prop()`only gets the propery and not setting it. `.attr()` sets and gets attributes like the way you want it to.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following

```
$(".pagination-next").attr("disabled","disabled");
```

In general I don't think anchors can be disabled as such.

[jQuery disable a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970388/jquery-disable-a-link)

This seems to be what you're after.