# Disable link button in laravel after click

Tags: jquery, laravel

I am trying to add disabled class to bootstrap anchor button, but it does not work. I added it like below,

1. jquery>js>html
2. jquery>html>js

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var fewSeconds = 5;
  
  $('#dis').click(function() {
    var btn = $('#dis');
    btn.addClass('disabled');
    // alert('works');
    
    setTimeout(function() {
      btn.removeClass('disabled');
    }, fewSeconds * 1000);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="/posts" id="dis" class="btn btn-light me-2 my-2 rounded-pill" type="button">Posts</a>
```

Comment: Your question not clear. What's your purpose? U want anchor to be clicked but disable for next 5 second not to be clicked again ?

Comment: Yes, I want to disable it for 5 seconds.

Comment: The page is redirected after the `a` element is clicked, so what purpose are you expecting blocking the link after clicking it to have? The use will not be on the same page any more

Comment: Ok, I was on localhost and I cant find the change as it is very fast. It works here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery disable a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970388/jquery-disable-a-link)

Answer (score 0):

Use `preventDefault();` to disable the link.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.disabled').on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/" class="disabled">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

**jQuery code to disable is**

```
$('#dis).prop('disabled', true);
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var fewSeconds = 5;
  
  $('#dis').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var btn = $('#dis');
    btn.prop('disabled', true);
    
    setTimeout(function() {
      btn.prop('disabled',false);
    }, fewSeconds * 1000);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="/posts" id="dis" class="btn btn-light me-2 my-2 rounded-pill" type="button">Posts</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was on localhost and I cant find the change as it is very fast. It works here